# automatically get new Facebook posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api, cron-task

I'm writing an app that needs to automatically get a profile/page new posts ( doesnt need to be instant, can be a cron job ). Let's say I wanna "monitor" those profiles/pages. 
My question is : If the user is using my app, and I can get Facebook permission to read user_posts, is this possible to keep checking for new posts using cron job ?
2nd question : If user_posts permission is denied by Facebook, is there any other way to accomplish this ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

With User permission it's possible. Refer the following link.

[Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api)

Without user's consent I am not sure if it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any idea whether FB is gonna grant me that permission ?

Comment: @ChínhLê no, likely not. They expect your app to do something with the data that the permissions give access to, that more or less directly benefits the user experience in your app. Using them purely for background analysis is not an acceptable use case. But if you only want to use this app yourself, or with a very limited user base, you don’t need to submit for review; every user with a role in the app can be asked for any permission, reviewed or not.

Comment: Hey @CBroe, thanks for the info. What if my purpose is to import selected posts from their wall to my app to show on my own marketplace ?

Comment: That will depend on whether or not the reviewer can see a benefit for the user.

Comment: I see, I think I'll email them to ask before actually developing the app to avoid wasting effort. Do you think it's a good idea ?